# Diffrence between "Created On" and "Record Created On"

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM, when I'm, trying to set up a work flow, I get to choose the timeout to be related to a certain entity's creation time. There are three fields to relate to.

- *Record Created On*
- *Created On*
- *Modified On*

While the last one is very obvious, I can't see any logical difference between the two others.

Comment: If its foreignish its probably worth posting the system names (assuming they are english?), might be clearer what they do.

Comment: @JamesWood Not sure ehow to get to the system names. I'm not in a form. I'm in the work flow creator. On the form, they aren't listed (*created on* is but not the other) so I suspect that it's specific to the WF creation wizard.

Comment: You **could** change the displayed language of the system. *File -> options -> language* or something similar.

Comment: I updated your question. And by the way, when I try that, I only get *execution time* (to see *timeout* one needs to set up the process on a non-activity entity, apparently). I also get *Last Date Included in Campaign*, so it seems not to be a 1:1 relation between your scenario and mine. But that might be due to **my** setup, not yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that *Created On* (`createdon`) is filled out automatcally by the server when you actually create the record, while *Record Created On* (`overriddencreatedon`) will usually be *null* (unless the record was imported into CRM *and* you chose to explicitly override the record creation date to match when it was created in another system).

You should use the first and skip the latter, as it's not supported (as far I've got it right when I talked to a MVP about it). Why it show, she had no idea and neither do I. Maybe @JamesWood has a shot. He usually does. *(sucking-up in progress)*

I've never used the latter and I believe you'll keep your hair off-grey and on-head if you stick to the same approach.

From the SDK:

> The *createdon* attribute specifies the date and time that the record was created. To import data in the *createdon* attribute, map the source column that contains this data to the *overriddencreatedon* attribute.
>   During import, the record’s *createdon* attribute is updated with the value that was mapped to the *overriddencreatedon* attribute and the *overriddencreatedon* attribute is set to the date and time that the data was imported.
>   If no source value is mapped to the *overriddencreatedon* attribute, the *createdon* attribute is set to the date and time that the data was imported and the *overriddencreatedon* attribute is not set to any value.

- [Link to BlogSpot](http://ronaldlemmen.blogspot.co.uk/2008/01/overriddencreatedon.html)
- [Link to Social MSDN](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/sv/crm/thread/251c9ad8-61dd-4e3d-a5de-86fa75738d4c)

Comment: I'll try to accept some of the answers. Sorry. But I'd like to remove the text from the answer as it's got nothing to do with the CRM.

Comment: I'm not sure why use of the `overriddencreatedon` attribute would be unsupported (but I'm not an MVP... :P ) but it is my understanding that `createdon` will report the same value as `overrridencreatedon` (i.e. not the value that is present in SQL for `createdon`) whenever a record is retrieved, so there should be no reason to ever access `overriddencreatedon` (*Record Created On*)

Comment: @GregOwens Great edit. Helpful. As for the unsupported part,I believe it's got to do with the fact that the field is only used for CRM 4 and in 2011 it has no meaning. But this is only me guessing (I'm not a MVP, either). However, I don't want to bother her with a bunch of not-so-important question so perhaps we'll never gonna know. We're agreed that there's no point of using *overriddencreatedon* and that such should be avoided, aren't we? I thought it was a good question so I marked it +1.

Comment: Actually we're both a little wrong re: overriddencreatedon (see additional edit!). It does exist in 2011, but the underlying SQL value in `createdon` will match `overriddencreatedon` if a value has been set (contrary to my comment above)

Comment: Ah, that's why I've never used it. I try to avoid data imports more than gonorrhea. So far, so good. :D